# Execute the script and find path on the remote machine

Tags: bash, script

I'm trying to execute the following script to find a path of directory on remote path
I'm new to scripting and unable to understand as to where I am going wrong
Can someone please help me to correct it?

```
!/bin/sh
ssh ssmis "echo Hello I am Logged in  `hostname` and getting ready to transfer and convert your files ;source .bash_profile;array=(asd-005-cpu eims-asd-005-apcpu);
for item in ${array[*a]};
do
echo $item;
path2=find /nnn/n4/db4/health -type f "${item}" -print;
echo $path2;
done;"
```

Comment: the first 2 characters of the first line must be `#!`

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? please post any/all errors you are receiving or state exactly what is happening that differs from your expectations.

Comment: There is more or less not a single working line in that entire script. Have you pasted it incorrectly? Have you written it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Change the outermost double quotes to single quotes, otherwise your current shell will interpret and replace what you are sending to the remote server. Better still write a script in remote and execute that script remotely to avoid quoting issues.